# Anyone used HDA/AC97 codec with ARM uC?

Tags: sound

I've got bunch of spare HDA & AC97 codecs from mobos, is anyone was able to interface to them from usual ARM uC? Is it even possible?

Googling didn't helped me much. Any hints?

Comment: What are the actual parts?

Comment: ALC880, ALC850...

Comment: ...and the uC part as well? :D

Comment: Any vanilla ARM, STM32 or NXP :-)

Comment: Guessing you mean Cortex M3 (like the STM32).  Remember, though, the ARM family is huge.

Comment: There is a new proposal at Areas 51: [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies?referrer=lxeiaDBzsJIqpGpL-P5bMg2) where we invites experts in codec development work. Please join and invite others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the data sheet for the ALC880:

http://realtek.info/pdf/alc880.pdf

You will have problems interfacing it to an ARM, as it uses S/PDIF and an unusual high-speed serial interface. It could be done with a CPLD. Or, you could forget the ARM and do everything with an XMOS chip. The interface could be done in software, and the chips have DSP capability. They are often used for high-end audio processing.

The data sheet suggests that designers contact Realtek for details of application circuits, perhaps you should try that.

The other codec is probably similar.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this, but it's not S/PDIF, it's 4-wire serial... I am not very happy with requirement of exactly 24Mhz data clock, and this unusual IN/OUT/SYNC interface... :-/

Comment: WOW XMOS looks quite cool.

Comment: Some ARM9 cores support S/PDIF.

Comment: @Hendrik - That is precisely why "Any vanilla ARM" doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 1):

All wrong guys.  AC97 uses a TDM serial bus at 12.288MHz for data/communication, which can be interfaced to pretty any MCU with audio peripherals. Some of them even support the AC97 protocol directly.

SPDIF has nothing in common with AC97 codec interfacing to an MCU. SPDIF is an audio interface for the user of the device. Just as any other audio I/O. Of course you can interface it to a MCU (some of the adult ones offer SPDIF Tx/Rx peripherals), but in this case, the AC97 codec is interfaced over "AC97 bus" which is a TDM (time domain multiplexed) bus. Similar to I2S, to express that easier. Like an bidirectional SPI with frame sync signal.